# Getting validation to work for address in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm making a page that before the user submits they need to add their address.

For example: The user goes to the order confirmation and they forget to add their address and they fill in the rest of the page (the page has delivery/collection radio buttons and payment option radio buttons) when the user clicks on the confirm button the page needs to go back and give an error that the address wasn't entered.

The address portion of the page only has a "Add Address" button that takes the user to a form to enter their address.

Is there a way to do this. I thought maybe validation would work but I don't think I'm doing it correctly in this instance.

I have a hidden form that grabs some info and it has an address field in it so that it gets passed into the controller so that I can save it, but it's like it doesn't pick it up

My order-confirmation.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.public')
@section('content')
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <h1>Order Confirmation</h1>
        <?php
            $delivery = getDeliveryFee();
        ?>

        {{ $invoice_number }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-15">
                        @if($message = Session::get('success'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ $message }}

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        @if($message = Session::get('error'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                {{ $message }}

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Billing Information 
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse {{ !$errors->any() ? 'show' : '' }}" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="address">
                                            @if ($errors->confirmation_errors->has('delivery_address'))
                                                <div class="help-block text-danger">
                                                    <strong>Please add an address NOW</strong>
                                                </div>
                                            @endif

                                            @foreach($addresses as $address)
                                                @if(!empty($address->complex))
                                                    {{ $address->complex }},
                                                @endif
                                                <div>{{ $address->address }},</div>
                                                <div>{{ $address->suburb }},</div>
                                                <div>{{ $address->city }},</div>
                                                <div>{{ $address->province }},</div>
                                                <div>{{ $address->postal_code }}</div>

                                                <div class="row edit-delete">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                        <a class="btn btn-primary edit-button" href="{{ route('account.edit.delivery.address', [$address->id]) }}">Edit</a> 
                                                        <span>/</span>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                        <form action="{{ route('account.delete.delivery.address', [$address->id]) }}" method="post">
                                                            @csrf
                                                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                                            <button class="btn btn-danger delete-button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Delete</button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <a href="{{ route('account.add.address') }}" class="btn btn-dark float-right mt-15">Add Address</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" id="delivery-collection" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Delivery/Collection
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse {{ $errors->confirmation_errors->any() ? 'show' : '' }}" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p>
                                    Please select your delivery option
                                </p>

                                @if ($errors->confirmation_errors->has('delivery_collection'))
                                    <div class="help-block text-danger">
                                        <strong>Please select your delivery option</strong>
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                                <div class="delivery-option">
                                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input {{ $errors->confirmation_errors->has('delivery_collection') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="delivery-option" id="delivery" value="delivery">
                                    <label for="delivery" class="form-check-label">
                                        Delivery
                                    </label>

                                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input {{ $errors->confirmation_errors->has('delivery_collection') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="delivery-option" id="collection" value="collection">
                                    <label for="collection" class="form-check-label">
                                        Collection
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    Payment Options
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse {{ $errors->any() ? 'show' : '' }}" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                @if ($errors->has('payment_option'))
                                    <div class="help-block text-danger">
                                        <strong>Please select a payment option</strong>
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="payment-option">
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input {{ $errors->has('payment_method') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="payment_method" id="payfast-eft" value="payfast-eft">
                                            <label for="payfast-eft" class="form-check-label">
                                                EFT with PayFast
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    Review Your Order
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="collapseFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">Product</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Code</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach($products as $product)
                                            <?php
                                                $image = getImagesArray($product['item']['image']);
                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    @if(!empty($image))
                                                        <img src={!! asset("product_images/thumbs/$image[0]") !!}>
                                                    @endif

                                                    {{ $product['item']['title'] }}
                                                </th>
                                                <td>{{ $product['item']['supplier_code'] }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $product['qty'] }}</td>
                                                <td>R {{ $product['item']['price'] }}</td>
                                                <td>R {{ $product['price'] }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach

                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="4">
                                                <div class="float-right">
                                                    Sub Total       
                                                </div>
                                            </th>

                                            <td id="totalPrice" data-price="{{ $totalPrice }}">
                                                R {{ $totalPrice }}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr class="delivery-fees">
                                            <th colspan="4">
                                                <div class="float-right">
                                                    Delivery Fee
                                                </div>
                                            </th>

                                            <td id="delivery-price" data-price="{{ $delivery }}">
                                                R {{ $delivery }}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <?php
                                            $total = $totalPrice + $delivery;
                                        ?>

                                        <tr class="total-price">
                                            <th colspan="4">
                                                <div class="float-right">
                                                    Total:      
                                                </div>
                                            </th>

                                            <td>
                                                R <span id="completePrice"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="confirm-order-btn pb-15">
                                    @foreach($products as $product)
                                        <!-- BEGIN PAYFAST EFT -->
                                        <div class="payfast-eft" style="display: none">
                                            <form action="{{ route('payment.gateway') }}" method="POST">
                                                @csrf
                                                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="merchant_id">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="merchant_key">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{{ route('payfast.success') }}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{ route('payfast.cancel') }}"> 
                                                <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="{{ $invoice_number }}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="completePrice" value="">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{ $product['item']['title'] }}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="{{ $product['item']['description'] }}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="confirmation_address" value="">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="payfast_eft">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="delivery_collection" class="delivery_collection" value="">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="delivery_fee" class="delivery_fee" value="{{ $delivery }}">
                                                <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE ADDRESS IS ADDED TO THE HIDDEN FORM -->
                                                <input type="hidden" name="delivery_address" class="delivery_address" value="{{ $address }}">

                                                <?php
                                                    $success = url('payfast-success');
                                                    $cancel = url('payfast-cancel');
                                                    $notify = url('payfast-notify');

                                                    $original_str = getAscii('merchant_id=merchant_id&merchant_key=merchant_key&return_url='.$success.'&cancel_url='.$cancel.'&notify_url='.$notify.'&m_payment_id=01AB&amount='.$totalPrice.'&item_name=Test Item&item_description=A test product&email_confirmation=1&confirmation_address=email@domain.com&payment_method=eft');
                                                    $hash_str = hash('MD5', $original_str);
                                                    $hash = strtolower($hash_str);
                                                ?>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ $hash }}">

                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right confirm-payfast-order">
                                                    Confirm Order
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- END PAYFAST EFT -->
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var price = $("#totalPrice").data('price'); //get data-price by this syntax

            $('#completePrice').html(price);
            $('.completePrice').val(price);

            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="collection"){
                    $(".delivery-fees").hide('slow');

                    var price = $("#totalPrice").data('price'); //get data-price by this syntax
                    var deliveryprice = 0;  //get data-price by this syntax
                    var totalPrice = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(deliveryprice);

                    $('#completePrice').html(totalPrice);
                    $('.completePrice').val(totalPrice);
                    $('.delivery_collection').val('collection');
                    $('.confirm-order').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.confirm-payfast-order').removeAttr('disabled');
                }

                if($(this).attr("value")=="delivery"){
                    $(".delivery-fees").show('slow');

                    var price = $("#totalPrice").data('price'); //get data-price by this syntax
                    var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").data('price');  //get data-price by this syntax
                    var totalPrice = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(deliveryprice);

                    $('#completePrice').html(totalPrice);
                    $('.completePrice').val(totalPrice);
                    $('.delivery_collection').val('delivery');
                }
            });

            /* BEGIN EFT PAYFAST */
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="payfast-eft"){
                    $(".payfast-eft").show('slow');
                    $(".payfast-card").hide();
                    $(".i-pay").hide();
                    $(".confirm-order").hide();
                    $(".payfast-debit-card").hide();
                }       
            });
            /* END EFT PAYFAST */
        });
    </script>   
@stop
```

my controller function

```
public function paymentGateway(Request $request)
{

    if($request->payment_method == 'payfast_eft')
    {
        $process = 'Order Paid';
        $paid = '1';
    }

    if($request->delivery_collection == 'collection')
    {
        $delivery_fee = null;
    }else{
        $delivery_fee = $request->delivery_fee;
    }

    $orders = Order::all();

    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->getRules());

    if($validation->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->route('cart.deliveryConfirmation')
            ->withErrors($validation, 'confirmation_errors')
            ->with('error', 'There were validation errors');
    }

    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        $order = Order::find($order->id)->where('invoice_number', $request->m_payment_id)->first();

        $order->cart = serialize($cart);
        $order->address = $request->delivery_address;
        $order->delivered_date = null;
        $order->delivery_fee = $delivery_fee;
        $order->delivery_option = $request->delivery_collection;
        $order->process = $process;
        $order->order_date = Carbon::now('+2:00');
        $order->payment_method = $request->payment_method;
        $order->paid = $paid;
        $order->order_price = $request->amount;

        $order->save();
    }

    $merchant_id = $request->merchant_id;
    $merchant_key = $request->merchant_key;
    $return_url = $request->return_url;
    $cancel_url = $request->cancel_url;
    $m_payment_id = $request->m_payment_id;
    $amount = $request->amount;
    $item_name = $request->item_name;
    $item_description = $request->item_description;
    $email_confirmation = '1';
    $confirmation_address = 'email@domain.com';
    $payment_method = $request->payment_method;
    $signature = $request->signature;

    if($request->payment_method == 'payfast_eft')
    {
        $url = 'https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process?merchant_id='.$merchant_id.'&merchant_key='.$merchant_key.'&return_url='.$return_url.'&cancel_url='.$cancel_url.'&m_payment_id='.$m_payment_id.'&amount='.$amount.'&item_name='.$item_name.'&item_description='.$item_description.'&email_confirmation='.$email_confirmation.'&confirmation_address='.$confirmation_address.'&payment_method='.$payment_method;
    }

    return redirect()->to($url);
}

protected function getRules()
{
    return [
        'delivery_collection' => 'required',
        'payment_method' => 'required',
        'delivery_address' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.8

Comment: When you say it doesn't pick it up do you mean that the validation doesn't fail even if the address is empty?

Comment: yep. so when I confirm the order it still goes through even though the address is empty

Answer (score 0):

basically on the `paymentGateway` controller you need to check whether the address is provided if not redirect to the previous page where address is selected and saved in db